# 'Delete' base member?

Tags: c#, inheritance, polymorphism, shadow, member-access

Is there a way to hide a member of the base-class?

```
class A
{
  public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class B : A
{
  private new int MyProperty { get; set; }
}

class C : B
{
  public C()
  {
    //this should be an error
    this.MyProperty = 5;
  }
}
```

Comment: No. There is not. [C# ascribes to the LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle). The best that can be done is to throw an exception; or use more refined Interfaces in some cases.

Comment: @pst: Eric Lippert has made it quite clear to me in several discussions that subtyping in C# does not use the Liskov definition.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would ever want to do this.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'd be interested in reading resources on the subject. Whenever I think of the LSP I generally only consider a mild form (e.g. mostly signatures and not necessarily invariants or all the other semantics it covers).

Comment: @casablanca, I'd like to do it since I overrode a base class that offers many methods to override, one of them uses a property, and I ommitted the usage of that property, so I thought about removing it.

Comment: @pst: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2007/10/17/covariance-and-contravariance-in-c-part-two-array-covariance.aspx as well as many of http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/covariance+and+contravariance/

Comment: @pst: Also, in a very different way, here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not a means to hide members in the C# language. The closest you can get is to hide the member from the editor, using [`EditorBrowsableAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.editorbrowsableattribute.aspx).

```
public class B : A
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    new public int MyProperty {
        get;
        set;
    }
}
```

I would dare say that there is no guaruntee that this will work for other editors than Visual Studio, so you are better off throwing an exception on top of it.

```
public class B : A
{
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public new int MyProperty {
        get {
            throw new System.NotSupportedException();
        }
        set {
            throw new System.NotSupportedException();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought initially, I just wanted to make sure there is not language-level means for it.